# CKAN Open Data how to upload to cpanel?

Tags: ckan

Im developing CKAN Open data and im configuring it with ubuntu 14.04, but it still hosted on localhost. Now, i want to upload my CKAN Open data Project to cpanel. Any help appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instructions for installing CKAN are here: http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/index.html

Comment: the project has finished, only need to hosting it

Comment: CKAN is an application and does not run on a host simply by 'uploading' it to the host. You need to install & deploy it, hence the instructions.